# Login with PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, authentication

I have a login webpage (login.php) where i want to redirect to another page(index.php) if the login is successful and throw a error message if unsuccessful in the login.php itself .

The flow is

```
login.php --->   verify.php ----> (if success) Redirect to index.php
          <----  verify.php 
(if fails) throw error message back in login.php
```

Currently , I have handled it as below in the AJAX call in the login page. But i dont want to do it in the client side .

```
if(http.responseText=="success"){
      window.location = '/index.php';
 } else {
      alert("Try Again");
 }
```

Below is the verify.php snippet. I want this file to redirect.

```
if (verification_is_correct) {   
  header("location:http://mysite.com/index.php");
  exit;
} else {
    echo "Incorrect username or password";
}
```

Please post your suggestions and solutions .

Thanks .

Comment: Why are you using AJAX? If you cannot code a login form, I suggest you forget about AJAX first and practice with just PHP. Look up PHP header() to redirect to index.php, include() to display the login form HTML.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if you are using the output of `verify.php`, you need to change your code this way:

```
if (verification_is_correct) {   
  // set session
  $_SESSION["user"] = $loggedin;
  die ("success");
} else {
  die("failed");
}
```

Comment: He said "But i dont want to do it in the client side." and he used header() in this verify.php. So i think he didn't know he could print the login.php template right from verify.php.

Comment: @Jake Yeah, in that case, he can give the same thing and change the redirect in the client side.